# AWS S3 Android sdk added files not visible

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded some files to my S3 bucket via the Android sdk.
I am able to process them on my Nodejs server using both a stream and a signed url.

They are not visible when I sign into S3 though.
I thought maybe it was because I was adding keys as folder eg. 'myfolder/myfilename.txt', but that wasn't the issue.

So I can process them fine but I need to be able to access them from the main S3 console on AWS.

I have a user set up with these permissions:

```
{
    "Statement": [
                {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::folder",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::folder/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you setting the access control list? you can use a canned one like this:

```
por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```